# mysql query with union and left join is slow

Tags: mysql, join, union

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (
    SELECT ProductID,ProductName,ProductCode,SampleRefNum 
    FROM products
    WHERE hidden = 'N'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT product_variants.ProductID,products.ProductName,product_variants.ProductCode,product_variants.SampleRefNum
    FROM product_variants
    JOIN products 
    ON product_variants.ProductID = products.ProductID
    ) AS p

LEFT JOIN stock_list AS s
ON p.ProductCode = s.ProductCode OR p.SampleRefNum = s.SampleRefNum
WHERE s.ProductCode IS NULL AND p.ProductCode IS NOT NULL AND p.ProductCode <> "" OR s.SampleRefNum IS NULL AND p.SampleRefNum IS NOT NULL AND p.SampleRefNum <> ""
```

The query above is extremely slow, 1 min. if i just do the union part its fast . or only use the products table and not union its fast

(what im doing here ? )
products have variants so i combining the product and the product variants to get a list of items which have product code and sample ref num. 
Then i'm joining to stock list (table with about 50 000 row of product codes and sample ref code from another system ) so i can get a list of any records that don't have a matching ProductCode or SampleRefNum

------------edit

i have indexes on ProductID , ProductCode, SampleRefNum on all tables

-- this is fast -----

```
 SELECT p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.ProductCode,p.SampleRefNum FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN stock_list AS s
ON p.ProductCode = s.ProductCode OR p.SampleRefNum = s.SampleRefNum
WHERE p.Hidden = 'N' AND (s.ProductCode IS NULL AND p.ProductCode IS NOT NULL AND p.ProductCode <> "" OR s.SampleRefNum IS NULL AND p.SampleRefNum IS NOT NULL AND p.SampleRefNum <> "" )
AND (p.ProductID NOT IN(SELECT ProductID FROM product_variants) )
```

--- this takes 10 sec

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (
    SELECT ProductID,ProductName,ProductCode,SampleRefNum 
    FROM products
    WHERE hidden = 'N'

    ) AS p

LEFT JOIN stock_list AS s
ON p.ProductCode = s.ProductCode OR p.SampleRefNum = s.SampleRefNum
WHERE s.ProductCode IS NULL AND p.ProductCode IS NOT NULL AND p.ProductCode <> "" OR s.SampleRefNum IS NULL AND p.SampleRefNum IS NOT NULL AND p.SampleRefNum <> ""
```

Comment: Could you post the explain plan?  Have you checked indexes?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally `join` with an `or` condition is going to be slow.  I would suggest that you rephrase the query using `exists` or simpler `left joins`.  However, you can try this with *two* left joins and see if this does what you want:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductCode, SampleRefNum 
      FROM products p
      WHERE hidden = 'N'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pv.ProductID, p.ProductName, pv.ProductCode, pv.SampleRefNum
      FROM product_variants pv JOIN
           products p
           ON pv.ProductID = p.ProductID
     ) p LEFT JOIN
     stock_list s1
     ON p.ProductCode = s1.ProductCode LEFT JOIN
     stock_list s2
     ON p.SampleRefNum = s2.SampleRefNum
WHERE (s1.ProductCode IS NULL AND p.ProductCode IS NOT NULL AND p.ProductCode <> '') OR
      (s2.SampleRefNum IS NULL AND p.SampleRefNum IS NOT NULL AND p.SampleRefNum <> '')
```

For this to work well, you will want two indexes on `stock_list`:  `stock_list(ProductCode)`, and `stock_list(SampleRefNum)`.

Note:  this is a possibility that this could return multiple rows, if there are multiple matches in `stock_list` on one key and none for the other.  I think your original query has the same issue.  Using a `not exists` clause would fix this.

EDIT:

The `not exists` would look like:

```
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (select 1
                   from stock_list s1
                   where p.ProductCode = s1.ProductCode
                  ) and
       p.ProductCode is not null and p.ProductCode <> ''
      ) AND
      (NOT EXISTS (select 1
                   from stock_list s2
                   where p.SampleRefNum = s1.SampleRefNum
                  ) and
       p.SampleRefNum is not null and p.SampleRefNum <> ''
      )
```

You would remove the `join`s from the `from` clause (and this wants the same indexes).